# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/conn/SchemeIOSessionStrategy

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am getting the below error while I am trying to run kafka elasticsearch sink conect, I have verified and I can see the required jar is available at the plugin.path location.

**List of Jars:**

```
/home/confluentkafka/confluent-5.3.1/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/
audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar  
gson-2.8.5.jar            
httpcore-nio-4.4.6.jar  
jsr305-3.0.2.jar                       
spotbugs-annotations-3.1.8.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar           
httpasyncclient-4.1.3.jar  
jest-6.3.1.jar          
kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar  
zkclient-0.10.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar         
httpclient-4.5.3.jar       
jest-common-6.3.1.jar   
netty-3.10.6.Final.jar                 
zookeeper-3.4.14.jar
common-utils-5.3.1.jar          
httpcore-4.4.6.jar         
jline-0.9.94.jar        
slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar
```

**Error Message:**

```
[2019-12-02 02:02:05,555] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/conn/SchemeIOSessionStrategy
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:122)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:51)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:300)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.conn.SchemeIOSessionStrategy
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 11 more
[2019-12-02 02:02:05,557] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:180)
[2019-12-02 02:02:05,557] INFO Stopping ElasticsearchSinkTask. (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask:185)
[2019-12-02 02:03:26,374] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:66)
```

**worker.proerties**

```
bootstrap.servers=00.0.0.000:6667 #fake IP
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/home/confluentkafka/confluent-5.3.1/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch
```

**Connect.properties**

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test
topic.index.map=test:twitter-index
connection.url=http://00.0.0.000:5601
type.name=test
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
```

Comment: Is your Elasticsearch host really at `http://00.0.0.000:5601` ? That (a) looks like an invalid IP address and (b) is usually the Kibana port, with Elasticsearch usually on `9200`

Comment: I have replaced the original IP with zeros here and port number is correct. I am able to access Kibana with this URL - http://00.0.0.000:5601

Comment: Right, but Kibana != Elasticsearch. If you try to send data intended for Elasticsearch to Kibana, it will fail.

Comment: I will check for this and try after updating, Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin path should be

```
/home/confluentkafka/confluent-5.3.1/share/java
```

That way, it'll load other classes provided by other connectors

Comment: when I am changing the plugin.path to this, its not able find below Jar which is available in this directory "kafka-connect-elasticsearch"

```[2019-12-02 21:39:37,520] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.getServerVersion(JestElasticsearchClient.java:231)```

Comment: Well, you no longer get a ClassNotFound. Now you seem to be getting an error about which versions of Elasticsearch server you are using. Kafka Connect only supports ES6, last time I checked